# How to map keys of dict to json in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am extracting data from a excel sheet and storing in a `dictionary` variable, for example:

```
data = {"customer_name":"XYZ", "customer_mobile":"989898", "customer_country":"country"}
```

Now I need to call a rest api to create a customer, need to send data in json as :

```
{
  "custName": "string",
  "custMobile": "string",
  "custCountry":"string",
}
```

The keys in `dictionary` and `json` are different and cant change either of them, so how can I map these two?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helps ?

```
data = {"customer_name":"XYZ", "customer_mobile":"989898", "customer_country":"country"}

dataToSend = {
    "custName" : data["customer_name"],
    "custMobile": data["customer_mobile"],
    "custCountry":data["customer_country"],
}

print(dataToSend)
```

I am creating a separate object `dataToSend` and populate its values from the data object that has values from the excel sheet .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could check against the common values in both keys:

```
data = {"customer_name":"XYZ", "customer_mobile":"989898", "customer_country":"country"}
api = { "custName": "string", "custMobile": "string", "custCountry":"string",}

for key in data.keys():
    for api_key in api.keys():
        if key[-3:] == api_key[-3:]:
            api[api_key] = data[key]
print(api)

>>> {"custName": "XYZ", "custMobile": "989898", "custCountry":"country"}
```

Checking the last 3 characters of each key inside each dictionary, you can compare and match the keys.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code sample which might help you.

```html
import json
def convert(word):
    word = word.replace('customer','cust')
    return ''.join(x.capitalize() or '_' for x in word.split('_'))

data = {"customer_name":"XYZ", "customer_mobile":"989898", "customer_country":"country"}

keys = data.keys()
for i in keys:  
  data[convert(i)] = data.pop(i)

r = json.dumps(data)
print (json.loads(r))
```

Answer (score 0):

[zip()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) function is used to change all keys of dictionary

```
api=["custName","custMobile","custCountry"]
data=dict(zip(api, list(data.values())))
```